# Using Python to populate a field based on multiple attribute criteria

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro

Based on results from multiple fields, I want to populate a results field with Fail, Partial Fail, and Pass. My criteria statements seem to be right, but I'm having trouble actually passing the results in my RESULTS field. Let me know if there's a simpler way to do this!

The error is "bad syntax in request" for line 35 which is the "for row in cursor:" line. RESULTS is a text field.

```py
import arcpy

arcpy.env.workspace = r"I:\Projects\path\to\.gdb"
# Feature class name

feature_class = "Curb_Ramps"

def CurbRamp_Evaluator(Slope_Running, Slope_Cross, Slope_Running_Left, Slope_Running_Right, Slope_Cross_Left, Slope_Cross_Right, Slope_Counter, Dim_Width):

    # Evaluating individual curb ramp slope criteria
    full_failure = any([
        Slope_Running >= 8.5,
        Slope_Cross >= 2.3,
        Slope_Running_Left >= 8.5,
        Slope_Running_Right >= 8.5,
        Slope_Cross_Left >= 2.3,
        Slope_Cross_Right >= 2.3
    ])

    # Checking for overall slope failure
    if full_failure:
        overall_result = "FAIL"
    else:
        # Checking for partial failure based on secondary criteria
        partial_failure = any([
            Slope_Counter >= 5.3,
            Dim_Width <= 47
        ])
        overall_result = "PARTIAL FAIL" if partial_failure else "PASS"
    return overall_result
    
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(feature_class, ["SlopeRunning", "SlopeCross", "SlopeRunningLeft", "SlopeRunningRight", "SlopeCrossLeft", "SlopeCrossRight", "SlopeCounter", "DimWidth", "RESULT"]) as cursor:
  for row in cursor:
    # Call the function to evaluate the curb ramp
    result = CurbRamp_Evaluator(row[0], row[1], row[2], row[3], row[4], row[5], row[6], row[7])

    # Update the "RESULT" field with the evaluation
    row[8] = result  # Update the "RESULT" field (index 8)

    # Save the changes to the feature
    cursor.updateRow(row)
```

Comment: So what exactly is the issue?  Are you getting an error when running part of the code?  If so, what is the error and traceback if available.  Are you getting unexpected results?  If so, what are you expecting and what are you getting?

Comment: Seems like the code is OK, so is your field "RESULT" actually a text field?

Comment: Please use the [edit] button beneath your question to revise it with any requested clarifications.

Comment: What is `feature_class`?  Is it a layer, or an actual feature class?  If it is a feature class (not a layer), try fully qualifying it's definition instead of just the feature class name.  Ie, `feature_class = r"I:\path\to\workspace.gdb\Curb_Ramps"`